# Clicking a button with Selenium button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on "Agree" button on this website https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=1# but it didn't work for me using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

s=Service("C:/Users/dhias/OneDrive/Bureau/stgg/chromedriver.exe")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=1#")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME," css-47sehv").click()
```

the `css-47sehv` is the class name of the button and here is a picture of the button [The blue button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p0bZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the element <kbd>AGREE</kbd> contains the classname *`css-47sehv`*, the value looks dynamic and may change in a short interval or once the application gets restarted.

---

### Solution

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=1#")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[mode='primary']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=1#")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@mode='primary' and text()='AGREE']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this**

`driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-47sehv').click()`

***on place of***

`driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME," css-47sehv").click()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure of following:

1-use explicitly Wait to wait the button to/Till appear

```
try:
    element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "AgreeButton"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

2-Click on the button with correct Xpath:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()='AGREE']").click()
```

3-If simple click doesn't work you can use JavaScript and perform methods to click.

Answer (score -1):

To click on `AGREE` button use the following `xpath` to identify the element and click.

```
//button[text()='AGREE']
```

Code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()='AGREE']").click()
```

---

Or Use following css selector.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.css-47sehv").click()
```